# Ошибка в passport-local

Tags: node.js, passport, логин

Локально все работает, после диплоя на сервер уже нет

auth.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from 'src/users/users.service';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(username: string, password: string) {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne({ where: { username } });

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('User not found');
    }

    const passwordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!passwordValid) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid pasword');
    }

    return {
      userId: user.id,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
    };
  }
```

authentificated.guard.ts

```js
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    return request.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

local.auth.guard.ts

```js
import {
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    await super.logIn(request);
    return result;
  }
}
```

local.strategy.ts

```js
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ContextIdFactory, ModuleRef } from '@nestjs/core';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()

export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }
  
  async validate(username: string, password: string, done): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(
      username.toLowerCase(),
      password,
    );

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return done(null, user);
  }
}
```

ну и контроллеры

```js
import {
  Controller,
  Header,
  Post,
  HttpCode,
  Body,
  UseGuards,
  Request,
  Get,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from 'src/auth/local.auth.guard';
import { AuthenticatedGuard } from 'src/auth/authentificated.guard';
import { ApiBody, ApiOkResponse } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import {
  LoginCheckResponse,
  LoginUserRequest,
  LoginUserResponse,
  LogoutUserResponse,
  SignupResponse,
} from './types';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly UsersService: UsersService) {}

  @ApiOkResponse({ type: SignupResponse })
  @Post('/singup')
  // @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @HttpCode(200)
  @Header('Content-type', 'application/json')
  createUser(@Body() dto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.UsersService.create(dto);
  }

  @ApiBody({ type: LoginUserRequest })
  @ApiOkResponse({ type: LoginUserResponse })
  // @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @Post('/login')
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @HttpCode(200)
  login(@Request() req) {
    return { user: req.user, msg: 'Logged in' };
  }

  @ApiOkResponse({ type: LoginCheckResponse })
  @Get('/login-check')
  @UseGuards(AuthenticatedGuard)
  async loginCheck(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }

  @ApiOkResponse({ type: LogoutUserResponse })
  @Get('/loginout')
  loginOut(@Request() req) {
    req.session.destroy();
    return { msg: 'Сессия завершена' };
  }
}
```

ну и мейн

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as passport from 'passport';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    }),
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api')
  // app.use(passport.session());

  app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders:
      'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Observe',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
    origin: true
  });

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

Выдает ошибку 403 при проверке на логин чек, логин и регистрация проходят без проблем